# MOSFET voltage drop seems way too high

Tags: mosfet, reverse-polarity, voltage

As discussed [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/583899/p-mosfet-reverse-polarity-protection-resistor-and-diode-or-not), I'm trying to use a MOSFET for reverse polarity protection.

I got an [IRFB7440PbF](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfb7440pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535616bde41e5b), which has a low Rds(On) (2mOhm,) suitable Vgs (I'm using a 5V power supply,) and what I thought would be a proper voltage drop.

I've tested it by simply connecting it between a 5V power supply and a Raspberry Pi (which would use less than 3A.) The Pi complained about low voltage. I measured 4.6V.

When reading the chart, I'm getting that the voltage drop should be 0.1V, so I should get around 4.9V:

[image: Drain to source volage depending on drain to source current]

What have I gotten wrong? Would you know any part that would meet my requirements? (5V @ 6A, dropping at most 0.2V)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I'm trying to use a MOSFET for reverse polarity protection.*

The IRFB7440PbF (unlike the MOSFET in your previous question) is an N channel device so it's unlikely you are able to use it for what you need: -

[image]

> *I've tested it by simply connecting it between a 5V power supply and a
> Raspberry Pi*

The volt drop you see is probably the forward volt drop of the parasitic bulk diode inside the N channel MOSFET and not the actual MOSFET itself.

Comment: Andy aka again... Thanks! And ouch... it's quite clear yet I missed it!

Comment: Every mistake you make of this type is less likely ever to be made again!